# How to change price according to variation in Woocommerce cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have two variations in my product. In cart page I need to choose the variations and with respective to variations I need to display the price.

How this can be done? Any track is welcome.

Kindly help me because I have searched a lot a solution for this, and I didn't anything yet that is working as I expect.

[image]

I have tried the following code in cart.php to get the variations.

```
<?php if( ! empty( $_product ) && $_product->get_type( 'variation' ) ){ 

$variation_attributes = $_product->get_variation_attributes();
$first_attribute = array_slice($variation_attributes, 0,1); 
$second_attribute = array_slice($variation_attributes, 1,2);    } ?>
```

By `$first_attribute` and `$second_attribute`, I populate the variations in a select box.

I have two attributes and four variations. So according to the variation I need to display the Price. I am not using third party PlugIn.

Comment: It seems that you are using some third party plugin that is customizing your cart as by default there is no select fields… 1) You should mention any related plugin (settings) and other related customizations… 2) You should include in your question the best code that you have tried that doesn't work. Without that your question is unclear and too broad.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec .I have edited my question.Kindly see it and give me a solution for this

Comment: You should add **all the related code** that you are using for that in your question. Please remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**"*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is already a part of WooCommerce's set up - as long as you have the variation set up specifically for X-license and X-plan you *should* be able to set the price to that variation.

**Variation Data**

Each variation may be assigned.

General:

- Regular Price (required) – Set the price for this variation.

Source and full documentation: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/

Comment: I have done this.I need to customize my cart page and i should change the License and Plan in cart page itself and need to display the price.